# Missing Combo Box in Custom draw application

Tags: mfc

I used custom draw control list with combo box in my application. I used following code to make the combo box in my list control.

```
SetExtendedStyle(LVS_EX_GRIDLINES | LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES | LVS_EX_FULLROWSELECT );
```

But when run my program combo box will disapper. How to resolve this problem ?

Also I want to select entire row using that combo box. How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be able to solve the above problem by following the content of the below site [1].

[1] http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21085/CheckBox-ComboBox-Extending-the-ComboBox-Class-and

Thanks !

Comment: Include the essential parts from the original source here, because answer would become useless if link becomes dead!